# Insert dictionary having single key multiple value in QTablewidget in p

Tags: python, dictionary, user-interface, pyqt5

[image: Dictinary with multipe value for single key]

For one of my automation i need to insert a dictionary with key in 1st column and multiple values attached to key in second column as shown in image above in qtablewidget .On googling i found some code
but didnt get how data[row][col] represents dictionary .Need help in correcting this code or better way to write if it is incorrect

```
self.tableWidget.setRowCount(len(dict))
self.tableWidget.setColumnCount(2)
for row in range(len(dict)):
    for col in range(2):
        item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(data[row][col], 0)
        self.tableWidget.setItem(row, col, item)
```

Comment: Please provide a [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) and show us the structure of the dictionary you're going to use.

Comment: like i shown in picture attached where A column header name  is key  and B column is value.Dictionary structure is like {'a.exe': ['a', 'b','c','d','e',f],'b.exe':['q',n','g','l'm',n','o']},Here value is list

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code you found is clearly for a different type of structure, which is probably something like this:

```
data = {
    0: ['a', 'b'],
    1: ['q', 'w'],
    ...
}
```

So in the case above accessing `data[row][col]` means that data[0][0] will be `a`, data[0][1] will be `b`, etc.

Besides that, in order to do what you're asking (which is not really related to the code you provided), you need to use [`setSpan()`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtableview.html#setSpan) (it's a method of QTableView, from which QTableWidget is inherited).

In the following example, I'm cycling through dictionary keys, create the first column item and the "sibling" items from the values corresponding to each key, then I use `setSpan` with the first item row and column, with a row span set to the length of the values, and a column span set to 1.

Note that I'm using `sorted(dict.keys())` for consistency, but if you're using Python >= 3.7 the keys are always sorted in the insertion order.

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets

structure = {
    'a.exe': [
        'a', 'b', 'c','d','e','f'
    ], 
    'b.exe': [
        'q', 'n', 'g', 'l', 'm', 'n', 'o'
    ]}

class Test(QtWidgets.QWidget):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(self)
        self.table = QtWidgets.QTableWidget()
        layout.addWidget(self.table)

        self.table.setColumnCount(2)
        for key in sorted(structure.keys()):
            values = structure[key]
            row = self.table.rowCount()
            self.table.insertRow(row)
            firstItem = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(key)
            self.table.setItem(row, 0, firstItem)

            for i, value in enumerate(values):
                if i:
                    # add rows only from the second item
                    self.table.insertRow(row + i)
                item = QtWidgets.QTableWidgetItem(value)
                self.table.setItem(row + i, 1, item)

            # set the table span for the "key" item
            self.table.setSpan(firstItem.row(), 0, len(values), 1)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Test()
    w.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: I am trying to use and understand it. I compiled the code and it exactly looked like what i wanted.Thanks and Regards